# python: chain elements of a tuple in a list of tuples

Tags: python

I want to find combinations of elements in a string. `baseString` is of variable length e.g. 'tbyhn' or 'tg' or so on.

I tried:

```
import itertools

baseString = 'tgby'
prd = [it for it in itertools.product(base,repeat=len(baseString)-1)]
```

`prd` is a list that looks like this:

```
[('t', 't', 't'), ('t', 't', 'g'), ('t', 't', 'b'), ..., ('y', 'y', 'y')]
```

I would like the list to look like this:

```
['ttt','ttg','ttb','tty','tgt',...,'yyy']
```

How can I do that?

Also, if I ever have a list of tuples like 'prd' how do I chain only the elements that are in each tuple.

**EDIT**

I didn't want these types of outcomes:

```
   x = ['t','t','t','t','t','g','t','t','b','t','t','y',...,'y','y','y']

   x = ['tttttgttbttytgt...yyy']
```

Comment: What do you mean by `chain only the elements that are in each tuple`?

Comment: what i meant by that is i don't want to flatten the entire list.

Comment: Could you please include an example for that in the question?

Comment: you've already provided the solution i needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply join them like this

```
bS = 'tgby'
prd = ["".join(it) for it in itertools.product(bS, repeat=len(bS)-1)]
```

**Edit:** A faster version, suggested by @alko in the comments

```
prd = map(''.join, itertools.product(bS, repeat=len(bS)-1))
```

Comment: yep that is what i was looking for. thanks. it looks like i can't accept the answer till a few mins.

Comment: equivalent expression `map(''.join, itertools.product(bS,repeat=len(bS)-1))`

Comment: @alko Interesting... `map` is faster in this case.